# Showing that $\int \frac{ \sinh (az)}{\sinh (\pi z)} \, e^{ibz} \, dz $ vanishes along three sides of a rectangle in the upper half-plane

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, hyperbolic-functions

One of several ways to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh (ax)}{\sinh (\pi x)} \, \cos (bx) \, dx \, ,  \quad  \, |a|< \pi,$$  is to sum the residues of $$ f(z) = \frac{\sinh (az)}{\sinh (\pi z)} \,e^{ibz}$$ in the upper half-plane.

But if you restrict $b$ to positive values, how do show that $\int f(z) \, dz$ vanishes along the right, left, and upper sides of a rectangle with vertices at $\pm N, \pm N + i\left(N+\frac{1}{2} \right)$ as $N \to \infty$ through the positive integers?

I think we can use the M-L inequality (in combination with the triangle and reverse triangle inequalities) to show that that integral vanishes along the vertical sides of the rectangle.

But showing that the integral vanishes along the top of the rectangle seems a bit tricky.

Comment: Try parameterizing the rectangle in the upper half plane and see if you can determine the order of growth along the extra four line segments other than the real line (two for the upper horizontal segment). The fact that $0<a<\pi$ is key here.

Comment: I think the above still admits simplification. The modulus of the sum of two complex numbers given that their moduli are fixed is maximized when they point into the same direction and minimized when they point into opposite directions.

Comment: There is a typo in going from line 1 to line 2 of your derivation and I don't think line 3 follows from line 2. The addition formulae for the hyperbolic sine are not really necessary here as I tried to explain in the previous comment.

Comment: Yeah, that made no sense.  I needed to minimize the denominator, not maximize it.  It is OK now?

Comment: You might want to do the other line segment (horizontal) and show how to sum the residues of the poles on the imaginary axis (looks like a geometric series).

Comment: Along the top of the rectangle, the absolute value of the integral appears to be bounded by  $$ e^{-b(N+\frac{1}{2})} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cosh at}{\sinh \pi t} \ dt$$

But unfortunately that integral doesn't converge due to a nonintegrable singularity at $t=0$.

Comment: This is what makes this into an interesting problem. Don't use a bound on the denominator, use the exact value. It simplifies because the scale factor π on the line t+i(N+1/2) produces some special effects where simple values appear and the supposed singularity disappears. You might nonetheless want to consider the left and right half plane component of the upper horizontal line separately.

Comment: Along the top of the rectangle, the absolute value of the denominator is $\cosh \pi t$. Then along the top of the rectangle, the absolute value of the integral is bounded by $$ e^{-b(N+\frac{1}{2})} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cosh at}{\cosh \pi t} \ dt $$ which goes to $0$ since the integral converges when $a < \pi $. Why would I need to break it up?

Comment: Good bound, that is what I was refering to. The only reason I suggested breaking it up was because the terms that dominate the hyperbolic cosine are not the same at minus and at plus infinity. If you consider this to be obvious there is no need to consider left and right separately. MSE says to close and this seems like a good moment.

Answer (score 2):

So that my question doesn't remain unanswered, I'm going to post an answer using the hints that Marko Riedel provided in the comments.

---

On the right side of the rectangle (and similiarly on the left side of the rectangle), we have

\begin{align} \left| \int_{0}^{N + \frac{1}{2}}  \frac{\sinh\big(a(N+it)\big)}{\sinh\big(\pi(N+it)\big)} \, i e^{ib(N+it)}  \, dt \right| &\le \int_{0}^{N + \frac{1}{2}} \left| \frac{\sinh\big(a(N+it)\big)}{\sinh\big(\pi(N+it)\big)} \, i e^{ib(N+it)} \right| \, dt \\  &\le  \int_{0}^{N+\frac{1}{2}} \frac{e^{aN}+e^{-aN}}{e^{\pi N}-e^{-\pi N}} \, e^{-bt} \, dt \\ &\le \left(N+ \frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{e^{aN}+e^{-aN}}{e^{\pi N}-e^{-\pi N}} \to 0 \ \text{as} \  N \to \infty\end{align} since $|a| < \pi$.

And on the upper side of the rectangle, we have

$$ \begin{align} \left| \int_{-N}^{N} \frac{\sinh \big(a(t+i(N+\frac{1}{2}) \big)}{\sinh \big(\pi (t + i (N+\frac{1}{2}) \big)} \,  e^{ib\left(t+i(N+1/2)\right)}  \, dt \right| &\le \int_{-N}^{N} \left|\frac{\sinh \big(a(t+i(N+\frac{1}{2}) \big)}{\sinh \big(\pi (t + i (N+\frac{1}{2}) \big)} \,  e^{ib\left(t+i(N+1/2)\right)} \right| \, dt \\ &\le \frac{e^{-b (N+1/2)}}{2} \int_{-N}^{N} \frac{e^{at}+e^{-at}}{\cosh \pi t}  \, dt \\ &< e^{-b(N+1/2)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh(at)}{\cosh(\pi t)} \, dt \to 0 \ \text{as} \ N \to \infty \end{align} $$ since the restriction $|a| < \pi$ means that$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh(at)}{\cosh(\pi t)} \, dt$ converges.